# Disable apple Cmd key on Centos/Gnome in VM

Tags: centos, gnome

I've installed Centos 7 in a VMware VM under MacOs. When I press the Command/Apple key, Centos arranges all of the windows and displays a search box.

This is annoying because I often use CMD-Tab to switch between applications on the mac.

How can I disable (or reassign the key) in Centos? I'd like Centos to ignore completely the CMD/Apple key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Gnome Wayland, switch to XOrg and it will start working normally.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/850202/983931 - Even though it's in "askubuntu" this should work on your Centos too, since the issue is not in the Linux distribution, but in Gnome instead.